# Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit

Tags: mysql, node.js

According to the Node MySQL documentation (https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#introduction):

`Every method you invoke on a connection is queued and executed in sequence.`

and

`Closing the connection is done using end() which makes sure all remaining queries are executed before sending a quit packet to the mysql server.`

Nevertheless, the code below doesn't work, because the `connection.end()` method is called before the SQL queries can run.  If I comment out the `connection.end()` line, it works, but the script hangs (doesn't close/end) when it completes, requiring me to hit ctrl-c to end it.

If I move the MySQL `connection` object and the `connection.end()` call into the `lineReader.createInterface().on()` block, it works - the script correctly terminates at the end...but it's creating a new connection for every `INSERT` statement.

It doesn't seem right to close and reconnect each time like that.  Am I misunderstanding the Node MySQL documentation?  Is there a better way?

```
let lineReader  = require('readline');
let file        = require('fs');
let mysql       = require('mysql');

let connection  = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 33060,
    user: 'homestead',
    password: 'secret',
    database: 'sentinel',
});

lineReader.createInterface({
        input: file.createReadStream('proxies/proxies.txt')
    }).on('line', function (line) {
        let ary = line.split(/[:, ]/);
        let insert_sql;

        if (typeof ary[2] !== 'undefined' && typeof  ary[3] !== 'undefined') {
            insert_sql =
                'INSERT INTO proxies (host, port, username, password) ' +
                'VALUES ("' + ary[0] + '", "' + ary[1] + '", "' + ary[2] + '", "' + ary[3] + '")';
        } else {
            insert_sql =
                'INSERT INTO proxies (host, port) ' +
                'VALUES ("' + ary[0] + '", "' + ary[1] + '")';
        }

        connection.query(insert_sql, function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('error: ' + error);
            } else {
                console.log('success: ' + insert_sql);
            }
        });

    });

connection.end();
```

Comment: **WARNING**: To avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) always escape *any* arbitrary data in your query by using [placeholder values](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values).

Comment: It's worth noting that the [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) library supports promises which makes chaining these sorts of operations together reliably a lot easier.

Comment: I initially tried to use a promise, but that resulted in only the first two lines of the file being processed (from a 50 line file)...which I thought was particularly strange.  But I abandoned that in favor of relying on the documentation's claim that all queries would be executed before quitting (when calling `.end()`).  I even tried setting the `multipleStatements` flag and building a query string with multiple statements...but, ultimately, that encountered the exact same problem - either the script would hang when finished (without `.end()`, or it would close prematurely (with `.end()`).

Comment: Using multiple statements in one query is almost always more trouble than it's worth. It's also hard to tell what's wrong from your description. It might be worth asking a new question with that promise-driven code specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `connection.end()` in a `close` event listener:

```
lineReader.createInterface({
        input: file.createReadStream('proxies/proxies.txt')
    }).on('line', function (line) {
      ...
    }).on('close', function() {
      connection.end();
    });
```

Comment: That works perfectly - thank you very much.  I should've been reading the 'readline' docs instead of the 'mysqljs' docs.  Any insights on the meaning of `Closing the connection is done using end() which makes sure all remaining queries are executed before sending a quit packet to the mysql server` in the 'mysqljs' documentation, though?  Am I misunderstanding how it's expected to work? ...or am I misunderstanding something about Node, in general?  I mean, I'm glad it's working now - I just want to understand why it didn't work before.

Comment: @CJG what happens is that any queries that are queued up _before_ calling `connection.end()` will be executed, but in your case, `connection.end()` is called and _then_ new queries are added.